# binomial determinant

Tags: matrices, determinant

Let $n > 0$, then :

$$ \det \left( {2n \choose n+i-j} \right)_{i,j=0}^{n-1} = \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{2n+i \choose n}{n+i \choose n}  $$

The LHS appears to be the determinant of a symetric Toeplitz matrix with binomial coefficients.

Does anyone have an idea on how to proove this formula ?

Comment: Where did you come across this formula?  Maybe there's a name for this kind of matrix that we can look up

Comment: This is found in the enumeration of the rhombic tillings of a regular hexagon of side length n. It is thus a simple case of the Macmahon formula for plane partitions, but it can apparently be computed "easily" without using such formula and that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You don't need to go through plane partitions. From what I understand, this formula (or, rather, its three-parameter generalization) is the easier half of the classical proof of MacMahon's plane partition counting formula. See, e.g., Theorem 8 in [my *A hyperfactorial divisibility*](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/hyperfactorialBRIEF.pdf) for a proof just using basic properties of determinants (though I write the right hand side as a quotient of hyperfactorials rather than as a product of quotients of binomial coefficients; but these should be easily seen to be equivalent).